How to make a hyperlink appear to the right of the page?
I just started development and i am using HTML. I was wondering how to make a hyperlink appear on the right of the page while already having one on the left side.
To clarify more I will use the code here.
<nav>
     <p>
        <a href="index.html">Home </a>
        <a href="Contact.html" target="_blank";>Contact</a>
     </p>
</nav>

Here I want that my second hyperlink i.e. Contact appear to the rightmost of the line on my page while Home remaining on the left end.
I tried to search online but found nothing, whatever I found I tried but that didn't work.
I tried using align tag in many ways but none gave the desired result.

You can use Flexbox:


nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
<nav>
  <ul>  
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>



or Float:


.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
<nav>
    <a href="index.html" class="left">Home</a>
    <a href="Contact.html" target="_blank" class="right">Contact</a>
</nav>




Could you also tell how to leave certain amount of pixels or spaces in between say I want Conatct not on right but after 60 pixels from Home.

to do this, Flexbox is a good solution, you can replace the old css with this snippet
nav ul {
display: flex;
gap: 60px;
}
